# I can't change font-family on codrops dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, icons, text-formatting

It's about [Tympanus Codrops Dropdown Menu - SimpleDropDownEffects](http://tympanus.net/Development/SimpleDropDownEffects/)

I can't change the font-family (I use Icomoon for the icons, which works, but I can't have my text formatted the way I want it to).

What's strange is that I can set font-size, font-style, weight and color of my **.cd-dropdown ul li span**, but not the font familly (ie : Arial, Trebuchet, etc) which remains in TimesNewRoman. I'm sure that the font I want to use is included properly etc.. I don't know where the problem stands..

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? It should not be a problem to change the font family.. Works for me on their live demo:

dropdown ul li span {
    font-family: impact;
}

Comment: Hi I've tried everything... What's strange is that I can set font-size, font-style, color and so on to my .cd-dropdown ul li span, but not the font familly (ie : Arial) which remains in TimesNewRoman. I'm sure that the font I want to use is included properly etc.. I don't know where the problem stands.. Thanks; I user their style6.css

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
background: #f4f4f4 url("../images/grid_DominikKiss_SubtlePatterns.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0;
color: #333;
font-family: "Lato",Calibri,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 300;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

}

They have their font declaration coming from the body tag, see if changing that helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I've tried that, as well as passing font-family directly in body, select, #select, li, etc, and everywhere in their & my stylesheets, helplessly. I might be missing something, but what & where ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Delete the font-size from the body and declare whatever you want on **.cd-dropdown ul li**

As an example(Your Code):

```
.cd-dropdown ul li {

     font-size: 4vw;
        z-index: 1002;
        top: 130px;
        left: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: none;
        transition: all 300ms ease;
        width: 300px;

}
```